# Showing a statement about conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let X and Y be independent random variables and let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded measurable. How do you show that $E(f(X,Y)|Y) = h(Y)$ where $h(t) = E(f(X,t))$.

So, basically I have to show that $f(X,Y)$ is independent of $Y$. right? and how is it done?

Comment: The statement is wrong. The correct statement is that
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \: | \: Y=y] = \mathbb{E}[f(X,y)]$$
and thus
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|Y] = h(Y),$$
where $h(y)=\mathbb{E}[f(X,y)]$.

Comment: @Leander Tilsted Kristensen Yes, indeed. Can you also prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments the actual statement that we should prove is, that
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|Y] = h(Y)$$
where $h(y)= \mathbb{E}[f(X,y)]$.
Now clearly $h(Y)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and bounded, since $f$ is bounded. It remains to be proven, that

$$\int_A h(Y) \: dP = \int_A f(X,Y) \: dP$$
for any $A \in \sigma(Y)$. So let $A \in \sigma(Y)$ and write $A=\{Y \in B\}$ for some borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
\int_A f(X,Y)  \: dP &= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{B}(y) f(x,y) P_X(dx)P_Y(dy) &\text{(by independence)} \\
&= \int_B \Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)P_X(dx) \Big) P_Y(dy) \\
&=\int_B \mathbb{E}[f(X,y)] P_Y(dy)  \\
&= \int_B h(y) P_Y(dy) \\
&=\int_A h(Y) \: dP
\end{align*}
And we have thus proven that $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|Y] = h(Y)$.

It is very important to note, that in general
$$h(Y) \neq \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)]$$
and also in general $f(X,Y)$ is not independent of $Y$.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you